# Good references for Expander graphs

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph) page give a nice general look for expander graphs. However  I'm looking for  more comprehensive reference.

Could anyone please suggest  some **references** for expander graphs? (books/surveies online/printed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My port of first call is [Hoory/Linial/Wigderson, *Expander graphs and their applications*, BAMS 2006](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-06-01126-8).
This is mostly focused on links with computer science.
(The focus of Lubotzky's survey is the use of expanders in mathematics itself.)

Answer (score 2):

What about Lubotzki's [survey article](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2012-49-01/S0273-0979-2011-01359-3/S0273-0979-2011-01359-3.pdf)?